# LINQ - Where a string contains any element in an array

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following block of code:

```
string[] searchTerms = Request.QueryString["search"].Split(' ');
var searchResults = from i in Website.Images
                    join u in Website.Users on i.User_Id equals u.Id
                    where i.ImageTitle == searchTerms.Any()
```

`searchTerms` will contain multiple words, for example `foo` `bar` and `baz`. I want to check i.ImageTitle to see if it contains any of these words. So:

**foo**tball will be returned

**bar** will be returned

**ba**th will not be returned

I'm sure I have to use .Any and probably .Contains, but I'm not sure how to configure them.

Answer (score 3):

The first thought is this:

```
var searchResults = from i in Website.Images
                    join u in Website.Users on i.User_Id equals u.Id
                    where searchTerms.Any(
                                term => i.imageTitle.Contains(term))
                    select i;
```

However, that is not quite correct, as you would be getting an error:

> Exception information:
>       Exception type: System.NotSupportedException
>       Exception message: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator.

This happens because the `searchTerms` array can't be translated to SQL construction.

The usual work-around is to use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to create a predicate from multiple search terms, and then use it in a final query:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<YourImageType>();
foreach(string searchTerm in searchTerms)
   predicate = predicate.Or(image => 
                      image.imageTitle.Contains(searchTerm));

var searchResults = from i in Website.Images.Where(predicate)
                    join u in Website.Users on i.User_Id equals u.Id
                    select i;
```

Comment: Doing that gives the error: System.NotSupportedException: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

Comment: The select clause is missing, that's all

Comment: No, even with the select clause in there it produces the same error.